# Slim autoloader & namespace issue

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, slim, autoload

I reckon my problem is quite common but even with the mass of doc on namespacing I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

So I'm using Slim 4.1 and I've put my workfiles in the folder `Custom/` in the `app/` folder.

`public/
-- index.php
app/
-- Custom/
---- routes/
------ manage.route.php
-- routes.php
src/`

I added this line to compose.json.

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Custom\\": "app/Custom/" // my custom line
        }
    }
```

In routes.php I try to call my file using `use` and the namespace of my files as follow:

`use Custom\Routes\Manage as Manage;`

and in my class's file:

`namespace Custom\Routes\Manage;` at its top;

When I hit `new Manage();` in routes.php I produce the folling error:

`Class 'Custom\Routes\Manage' not found in '[directories]/routes.php'`

I'm pretty sure composer loads the files as the number of files autoloaded changes when I remove the namespace calls.

Maybe I'm not calling my Class the right way, I truly don't know at this point.
Could you point me the way ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Edits:

I also reloaded composer with `composer dump-autoload -o`

Composer is adding my folder so the problem isn't from there, it's written in vendor/composer/autoloader_psr4.php 
`'Custom\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/Custom')`

Comment: Your namespace should be (I think) `namespace Custom\Routes;` as I think it's creating your class as `Custom\Routes\Manage\Manage`

Comment: I can't beleive I wasted hours for something that trivial! I salute you Sir Nigel savior of time. It works. If you want some more reputation you could post a proper answer I'll gladly select it as the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Please read https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: The funny thing is that I've read it while looking for an answer, I just didn't want to see I guess. I wanted it to be a bigger problem :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nigel Ren pointed out it was just a namespace issue.

> Your namespace should be (I think) namespace Custom\Routes; as I think it's creating your class as Custom\Routes\Manage\Manage"